# Pseudo number generation

Tags: algorithm, random

Following is text from Data structure and algorithm analysis by Mark Allen Wessis.

Following x(i+1) should be read as x subscript of i+1, and x(i) should be
read as x subscript i.

x(i + 1) = (a*x(i))mod m.

> It is also common to return a random real number in the open interval
>   (0, 1)  (0 and 1 are not possible values); this can be done by
>   dividing by m.  From this, a random number in any closed interval [a,
>   b] can be computed by normalizing.
>
> The problem with this routine is that the multiplication could
>   overflow;  although this is not an error, it affects the result and
>   thus the pseudo-randomness.  Schrage gave a procedure in which all of
>   the calculations can be done on  a 32-bit machine without overflow. We
>   compute the quotient and remainder  of m/a and define these as q and
>   r, respectively.

In our case for M=2,147,483,647 A =48,271, q = 127,773, r = 2,836, and r < q.

We have

```
 x(i + 1) = (a*x(i))mod m.---------------------------> Eq 1.
          = ax(i) - m (floorof(ax(i)/m)).------------> Eq 2
```

Also author is mentioning about:

```
 x(i) = q(floor of(x(i)/q)) + (x(i) mod Q).--->Eq 3
```

My question

1. what does author mean  by random number is computed by normalizing?
2. How author came with Eq 2 from Eq 1?
3. How author came with Eq 3?

Answer (score 3):

1. Normalizing means if you have X ∈ [0,1] and you need to get Y ∈ [a, b] you can compute

   Y = a + X * (b - a)

**EDIT:**
2. Let's suppose

```
a = 3, x = 5, m = 9
```

Then we have 
[image]

where `[ax/m]` means an integer part.
So we have `15 = [ax/m]*m + 6` 
We need to get 6. `15 - [ax/m]*m = 6` =>  `ax - [ax/m]*m = 6` => `x(i+1) = ax(i) - [ax(i)/m]*m`

Comment: Hi @Shymep, what "e" stands above

Comment: Means "belongs". a ∈ S means a is an element of the set S (c)

Comment: I gave an answer to the second question. You can get the third similar.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have a random number in the range [0,1], you can get a number in the range [2,5] (for example) by multiplying by 3 and adding 2.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth sorry i didn't get it is quite a long time i read mathematics can u pls elobrate?

Comment: @venkysmarty: I don't know how I can explain it any more simply.  If you take any number in the range [0,1] and multiply it by 3 and then add 2, you will get a number in the range [2,5].

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth why are we taking only multiplying with 3 and adding 2? is this should be selectaed in range [2,5]?

Comment: @venkysmarty: It's an example.  You can use the same technique to get a number in any range you like.